# Sync Qthreads on different infinite loops (QTimerEvent)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, infinite-loop, qthread

Considering a Qt project. I have defined different Qthreads to do my calculations in timerEvent of each class and show the results on QMainWindow. (Class A, B and C are the same and only the content of `printf()` would be changed!)

Here is `a.h`

```
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit A(QObject *parent = 0);
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *);

private:
    int timerId;
};
```

and `A.cpp` is:

```
A::A(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    timerId = startTimer(1000);
}

void A::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *)
{
    printf("A\n");
}
```

The `main.cpp` is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThread thread_1, thread_2, thread_3;

    A objA;
    B objB;
    C objC;

    objA.moveToThread(&thread_1);
    objB.moveToThread(&thread_2);
    objC.moveToThread(&thread_3);

    thread_1.start();
    thread_2.start();
    thread_3.start();

    return a.exec();
}
```

please consider that I cannot change the layout of my classes. The question is How can I sync my Qthreads in these situations? The results of each class has no dependencies but I have to be sure that all the results are available on each second and in the same order. For instance the results must always be shown as A B C   A B C   A B C ... Thank you!

Comment: If you want sequential processing, do you really need to use separate threads?

Comment: "I want to do something else, but I can't change my code" With that attitude you can pretty much just give up :(

Comment: @KubaOber some guys help but guys like you just moan! I cannot understand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible. Execution time of the code running in the threads will vary, as the cores shared with the rest of the `OS`, and it will vary and how long they are active. Enough that the order might change, and you can guarantee. 
   Most concurrent systems use linear segments for this point, like process all tasks in parallel, put the results into a queue and when the parallel section finished, sort it (like by and id) and then process.

You can try `MapReduce` in `QtConcurrent`. Or try task dependencies, but that will essentially telling the system to run `C` after `B`, and `B` after `A`, making it sequential. You will need to think about what ordering constraints you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the classes A, B and C, you can still make a managing class which is moved to its thread, owns A,B and C objects, has an event-timer and upon timeouts calls the `timerEvent()` functions in the correct order.

This makes more sense since the result is expected to be in order.

If however, this is an exercise on thread synchronization, you should wrap these classes in classes that can do some kind of synchronization like condition variables letting the next class know that the current class is finished.